# Write query for get info from mongo from specific document structure

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Imagine I have this document structure:

```
DocumentOne
{
  string Id { get; set; };
  string InnerId { get; set; }
  DocumentTwo[] InnerDocuments { get; set; }
}

DocumentTwo
{
  string Id { get; set; }
  string AnotherField { get; set; }
}
```

I try to write query to filter documents by condition `DocumentOne.InnerId != DocumentTwo.Id` in .net using mongodb driver.

I tried to use

```
Builder<DocumentOne>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.InnerDocuments, y => y.Id != ???)
```

but I cannot access InnerId in this query (question marks)

If I try to use Fluent Syntax like

```
database.Find(x => x.InnerDocuments.Contains(y => y.Id != x.InnerId))
```

or

```
database.Find(!x => x.InnerDocuments.Any(y => y.Id != x.InnerId))
```

I got error message from driver.

How I need to re-write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 ways to do this, either by aggregation or using a find with a [expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/).

We'll take a look at aggregation, as to me it flows a bit easier.

So starting off wtih we'll have 2 models for MongoDB like you said

```cs
    public class DocumentOne
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string InnerId { get; set; }
        public DocumentTwo[] InnerDocuments { get; set; }
    }

    public class DocumentTwo
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string AnotherField { get; set; }
    }
```

Then we'll need a second projection to keep track of things later down the line when we unwind the inner documents:

```cs
    public class DocumentOneProjection
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string InnerId { get; set; }
        public DocumentTwo InnerDocuments { get; set; }
    }
```

So we'll throw some data in to MongoDB to play around with

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<DocumentOne>("documents");

await database.DropCollectionAsync(collection.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName);

await collection.InsertManyAsync(new[]
{
    new DocumentOne()
    {
        Id = "1", InnerId = "10", InnerDocuments = new[]
        {
            new DocumentTwo()
            {
                Id = "11"
            }
        }
    },
    new DocumentOne()
    {
        Id = "2", InnerId = "20", InnerDocuments = new[]
        {
            new DocumentTwo()
            {
                Id = "20"
            }
        }
    },
    new DocumentOne()
    {
        Id = "3", InnerId = "30", InnerDocuments = new[]
        {
            new DocumentTwo()
            {
                Id = "30"
            },
            new DocumentTwo()
            {
                Id = "31"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then we'll be able to create an aggregation query

```cs
var items = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind(x => x.InnerDocuments)
    .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(
        @"{ $addFields: { matchInner: { $cmp: [ ""$InnerId"", ""$InnerDocuments._id"" ] } } }")
    .Match("{ matchInner: { $ne : 0 } }") // 0 if the two values are equivalent.
    .AppendStage<DocumentOneProjection>(
        @"{ $unset: ""matchInner"" }")
    .ToListAsync();
```

This query starts off with unwinding all the inner documents, this will create a document for each document in the array (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Then it creates a new field that we will then create a match on later, this uses a compare ($cmp - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/)

Then we just match the new field and then execute the query to get back the documents.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds good, I tried this - works as expected. But I need another condition - no identifier `DocumentOne.InnerId` equals any Id in nested array `InnerDocuments`

Comment: I need get documents where any InnerDocuments Id is **not equal** DocumentOne.InnerId

Comment: This query does this `{ matchInner: { $ne : 0 } }` `$ne` is not equal